# DynamoDB Table Design Suggestion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, bigdata

Need guidance to design a DynamoDB table.
Below is my sample data.

| FinanceType | ModelName | ModelCode | ModelYear | MoreAttributes ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lease | Avalon | TA1 | 2021 | ..... |
| Lease | Camry | TC1 | 2021 | ..... |
| Lease | Sienna | TS1 | 2021 | ..... |
| Loan | Avalon | TA1 | 2021 | ..... |
| Loan | Camry | TC1 | 2021 | ..... |
| Loan | Sienna | TS1 | 2021 | ..... |
| Lease | Avalon | TA1 | 2020 | ..... |
| Lease | Camry | TC1 | 2020 | ..... |
| Lease | Sienna | TS1 | 2020 | ..... |
| Loan | Avalon | TA1 | 2020 | ..... |
| Loan | Camry | TC1 | 2020 | ..... |
| Loan | Sienna | TS1 | 2020 | ..... |

A Combination of `FinanceType + ModelCode + ModelYear` makes a record unique.
Access pattern would be to find **MoreAttributes** for a given **FinanceType, ModelCode & ModelYear**.
How do I design my table to have the right partition key and a sort key such that the data is evenly distributed and there are no hot partitions?

Comment: why dont you add a attribute called as serial number which is unique hence become the PK and model name as sort key so that you can query multiple records based model name and then filter out for more attributes

Comment: The table design needs to be done based on your access patterns. So just knowing the fields is not enough to have a good table design. If you are not sure what are you access patterns, you will maybe end up needing to create GSI's - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html.

Another option if you for some reason don't want to use GSI you can leverage dynamodb streams to have another DB as your reporting storage with more flexible querying capabilities.

Comment: @GuilhermeBrabo. Do you think my latest comment on the below answer is a good choice for PK and SK?

Comment: @DenilParmar, again, without knowing your access patterns/data distribution any recommendation can be misleading. If you have millions of items per financetype looks like a bad design, If your table has 100 records and you are not worried about scaling than maybe it's fine. So it's all about your data structure. 
It's very important that you understand how data distribution works and the implications of having a partition key with just 2 values:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html

Answer (score 2):

I think a [composite key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/) if the form of:

```
FinanceType#ModelCode#ModelYear
```

would be enough. If you want you can make `ModelName` as a sort key.

Comment: I think @Marcin solution is the recommended wayf from amazon too https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/

Comment: If that's the case, then for example my record would look like  
Pk=Lease#TA1#2021 ... with this every logical partition will receive only one record as this combination is unique for each record. So for every N records there would be N partitions created with each partitions having only one record. Is that right? .Guide me guys if I am wrong. @Jatin Mehrotra

Comment: No, you don't get a physical partition per partition key. The key is what's used to help assign the physical partition. Go with what @Marcin suggested.

Comment: @DenilParmar There are no individual partitions per key. The way I answered you is the recommended setup for your use-case.

Comment: Hey @marcin! your solution is the best. The only problem with your approach I see is the partitionKey having a very high-cardinality! While is the best solution and fits my needs to display on the frontend, but might be a bottleneck if I need to extract a report.

I was thinking pk="financeType" & sk="modelCode#modelYear". This could give me some reports like )
1. Give me all "loan records"?  Query: pk="Loan"  2. Give me loan records for all Camry? Query: pk="Lease" sk=begins_with("TC1")   3. Give me loan record just for Camry 2021. Query: pk="Lease" sk="TC1#2021". Let me know your thoughts

Comment: Based on my above comment and approach, primaryKey will have only two values. 1. Loan 2. Lease. 
Let me know if it would be the right approve @Marcin